# NoClassDefFoundError with gradle multi projects

Tags: java, gradle

I have setup a gradle multi project in java. The build was successful but when I tried to run the JAR, a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError was thrown.

Here is my project structure:

```
.gradle/
authserver/
    build/
    src/main/java/fr/evywell/robserver/auth/
        Main.java
build/
common/
    build/
    src/main/java/fr/evywell/robserver/common/
gradle/
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

And then my configuration:
settings.gradle (IN ROOT DIR)

```
rootProject.name = "robserver"

include 'authserver'
include 'common'
```

build.gradle (IN ROOT DIR)

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

build.gradle (IN common DIR)

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.24.Final'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.16'
    compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.25.0-GA'
    compile group: 'com.jsoniter', name: 'jsoniter', version: '0.9.23'
}
```

build.gradle (IN authserver DIR)

```
apply plugin: 'application'

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.24.Final'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.16'
    compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.25.0-GA'
    compile group: 'com.jsoniter', name: 'jsoniter', version: '0.9.23'
    compile project (':common')
}

mainClassName = 'fr.evywell.robserver.auth.Main'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'fr.evywell.robserver.auth.Main'
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fr/evywell/robserver/common/network/Server
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fr.evywell.robserver.common.network.Server
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

The error message says that it cant find a class in my `common` package. 
I don't know why because I used `compile project (':common')` in my authserver gradle configuration

Here is the command: `java -jar authserver/build/libs/authserver.jar`

Thank you for your help and have a nice day !

Answer (score 1):

For me worked next thing: in kotlin I haved spring boot plugin applied to all subprojects {} in root build.gradle

Instead of this I've removed
`apply(plugin = "org.springframework.boot")` from root build.gradle and applied this line for each subproject **instead of** `common` module

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the JAR you are creating does not include the class files generated from compiling the common module.  Try ammending the jar task of authserver module so that you include the output of compiling the common module:

```
jar {
     from project.sourceSets.main.allSource
     from project(":common").sourceSets.main.java.output

     manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'fr.evywell.robserver.auth.Main'
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add those two lines, gradle build fail 
"
> No such property: output for class: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultSourceDirectorySet
  Possible solutions: outputDir
" Even with outputDir instead of output, the same exception is thrown

Comment: OK - can you confirm the version of gradle/ gradle wrapper you are using please.

Comment: Gradle 5.6.2 - Kotlin: 1.3.41 - Groovy: 2.5.4 - JVP 1.8.0_222

Answer (score 0):

I used the shadow plugin to build a "fat jar". I don't know if it's a good practice...

Thank you for your help !

```
// authserver/build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.1.0'
    id 'java'
}
apply plugin: 'application'

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'io.netty', name: 'netty-all', version: '4.1.24.Final'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.16'
    compile group: 'org.javassist', name: 'javassist', version: '3.25.0-GA'
    compile group: 'com.jsoniter', name: 'jsoniter', version: '0.9.23'
    compile project (':common')
}

mainClassName = 'fr.evywell.robserver.auth.Main'


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'fr.evywell.robserver.auth.Main'
    }
}
```

Comment: that `:common` library might simply lack an entry point. fat jar is the opposite of modular design.

Comment: The thing is the common package does not have an entry point because it's only utility classes. Should I create an empty entry point or something ?

Comment: just don't try to run it, as if it had one.